# Delete the comma from a string in csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging two csv files and trying to delete a comma from the Entity column, which exists in both csvs. Even though the script works fine and does not blow up the comma still shows up in both the individual csvs and the merged one. How can I delete the comma from the column?

```
import pandas as pd

first = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/first csv.csv')
first['project_id'] = 1
first['Entity'] = first['Entity'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(','))

second = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/second csv.csv')
second['project_id'] = 2
second['Entity'] = second['Entity'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(','))

merged = pd.concat([first, second], ignore_index = True)
merged.to_csv('C:/both files.csv', index=False)

Print "Let's get to work"
```

Comment: Are you saying it runs but doesn't work? are you after `first['Entity'].str.replace(',','')`?

Comment: `x.lstrip(',')` only remove leading commas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you remove it by:

```
first['Entity'] = first['Entity'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Replace commas with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Is Entity a number column?  Since you're already using Pandas, let it handle the comma for you:

```
 first = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/first csv.csv', thousands=',')
```

Comment: Thanks eduffy, Entity is a text/ varchar column.

Answer (score 0):

I used above approaches but for strings without commas it will give nan, which can be a problem where you have currency wise  formatted data with commas.

**This approach worked great for me:**

dataframe['Amt']  =  dataframe['Amt'].apply(  lambda x: int( str(x).replace(',', '') )  )